# How to retrieve all indexes of strings in a large file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

Imagine there is a very large html file with of course lots of html tags. I cannot load the entire file into memory.

My intention is to extract all indexes for this `<p>` and this `</p>` strings. How should I achieve it? Please suggest some directions for me to do it.

Comment: how large? like, say, a Gb Html file? where do you get that kind of html from?

Comment: @Simon Mourier: It doesn't not matter. I welcome your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example using file streams:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a collection of index,string for everything inside p tags in the html file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="htmlFilename">filename of the html file</param>
/// <returns>collection of index,string</returns>
private Dictionary<long, string> GetHtmlIndexes(string htmlFilename)
{
    //init result
    Dictionary<long, string> result = new Dictionary<long, string>();

    StreamReader sr = null;
    try
    {
        sr = new StreamReader(htmlFilename);
        long offsetIndex = 0;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {

            string line = sr.ReadLine(); //assuming html isn't condensed into 1 single line
            offsetIndex += line.Length;  //assuming 'index' you require is the file offset
            int openingIndex = line.IndexOf(@"<p");
            int closingIndex = line.IndexOf(@">");
            if ( openingIndex > -1)
            {
                int contentIndex = openingIndex + 3; // as in <p tag or <p>tag
                string pTagContent = line.Substring( contentIndex);
                if(closingIndex> contentIndex)
                {
                    int tagLength = closingIndex - contentIndex;
                    pTagContent = line.Substring( contentIndex, tagLength);
                }
                //else, the tag finishes on next or subsequent lines and we only get content from this line

                result.Add(offsetIndex + contentIndex, pTagContent);
            }


        } //end file loop

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle error ex
    }
    finally
    {
        if(sr!=null)
            sr.Close();
    }


    return result;
}
```

This has limitations which you can see from the comments.
I suspect using LINQ will be a lot neater. I hope this gives you a starting point?

Comment: This looks like it will also match a `<param>` or a `<pre>` tag and I can't see any logic for the closing `</p>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Using file streams you should be able to load the file in chunks of several kb in size.  Keep an index of your current file position as you load each chunk.  Scan the chunk for the string you are looking for, and add it's offset to you index.  Keep a list of all the indexes you find.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The Html Agility Pack is fantastic, but I have seen it buckle under large blocks of HTML. I imagine the OP is going to have issues parsing "large files". But, it's definitely worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

If your html is pure XHTML, then you could treat it as an XML document. Load your XHTML in a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and then use the `GetElementsByTagName("p")` method to return a list of <p>-tags. This is much safer and easier than trying to parse the html directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating an HTML tokeniser, which using `IEnumerable`, `yield return` etc would be straightforward. It could read a file char-by-char using `StreamReader.Read` and a state machine `switch` would decide current *state* and yield a sequence of tokens or `Tuple`s.

I found an old HTML tokenizer [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidCBB3C224CBBC330C8E738129BA2169022428EDF8.aspx) (part of Chris Anderson's old **BlogX** blog engine) that could be adapted to become the basis of a streamable solution to the problem.